# C# WPF | Change DisplayMemberPath programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a class `Person` with three properties `Name`, `LastName` and `FullName`.
I use MVVM - in the ModelView, I have a `List<Person> Persons`.

My view looks like this:

```xml
 <Button Content="LastName" Command="{Binding LastNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
  <ListView.View>
   <GridView>
     <GridView.Columns>
       <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
       <GridViewColumn Header="FullName"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" />
    </GridView.Columns>
   </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My goal is now to change the part

```xml
       <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

to

```xml
       <GridViewColumn Header="LastName"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
```

when I click on the button.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why you can't add new property to the Person NameOrLastName?

Comment: The reason is that I use another method that returns a collection of `Person`. Then I had to cast `Person`  to `MyPerson` or smth like that. And this is not easy possible, because I need some sort of converter to map a `Person` to `MyPerson`. And all that to display another value in the `Person` class. I would prefer something with less overhead.

Comment: A simpler solution is to just add `GridViewColumn` for LastName and switch the visibilities of `GridViewColumn`s for Name and LastName by changing thier `Width`.

Comment: @emoacht Can you provide code? in my understanding my modelview should not know anything about the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting or changing the `DisplayMemberBinding` property of a `GridViewColumn` should be done in the view.

The view model shouldn't know or care about any `DisplayMemberBinding`. It only updates the source properties (`Name` and `FullName` in this case).

So hook up an event handler for the button in the view and set the view-related property there:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    col1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("path");
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="LastName" Click="Button_Click" Command="{Binding LastNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="col1" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="col2" Header="FullName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This does not break the MVVM pattern in any way. Trying to modify a `DisplayMemberBinding` in a view model certainy does. MVVM is not about eliminating view-related code from the views. It's about separation of concerns.